# How to make objects not pass through each other when animating

Tags: animation

Is there some kind of way that I can make meshes not pass through each other when I'm animating them? Like maybe use rigid bodies or physics or something like that (sorry, i'm still new to Blender)? Like for example, if I want two people to handshake, how do I make it so that the hands don't go through each other? Or do I just have to animate it in such a way so that they don't?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do it other than fake it with your animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Soft body modifier after you animated the general movement.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/soft_body/index.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ofIi4ddHGW0

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uZHmo3iH4cE